# Google Static Maps rejecting my request, but its enabled

Tags: google-maps

I've been at this for hours now, tons of people seem to have the same problem but no one has an answer.

I'm trying to embed a static map into my website.

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=Phoenix%2C%20Arizona%2C%20United%20States&key=key"></iframe>
```

I am getting this error:

[image]

But I have the static maps API enabled in my console

[image]

Comment: can we presume that your actual URL contains your key?

Comment: yes, I removed it from this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a [static map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/)(static maps are images), it's a embedded map.

You must enable **Google Maps Embed API**-service

Comment: Thank you so much! I really do appreciate it!